# How to call a function on a thread's creation and exit?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, operating-system, posix

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void OnCreateThread()
{
    cout << "Create a thread." << endl;
}

void OnExitThread()
{
    cout << "Exit a thread." << endl;
}

void f(void*) {}

int main()
{
    //
    // What to do here ???
    //
    pthread_t dummy;
    pthread_create(&dummy, 0, f, 0);
    pthread_create(&dummy, 0, f, 0);
    while (true);
}
```

The code creates two native threads, **other than `std::thread`**, and I want it to output as follows:

> ```
> Create a thread.
> Create a thread.
> Exit a thread.
> Exit a thread.
> ```

It can be done under Windows by using FlsXXX functions.

However, I don't know whether it can also be done under Linux.

Is there a standard way under Linux?

Comment: Do you want to know how to use `pthread_create` or do you want to know how to get your desired output?

Comment: You will find all thread functions documented in your [pthreads(7) manual page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org//htmlman7/pthreads.7.html). If it's not documented there, it doesn't exist. The answer here is, literally, RTFM.

Comment: If you can't register those functions, you can still shadow pthread_create. I am just joking...

Answer (score 1):

> How to call a function on a thread's creation and exit?

Pthreads API does not provide callbacks for thread creation (nor does `std::thread` API).

Solution is pretty simple however: Call the functions at the beginning and end of `start_routine` callback.

```
void* f(void*) {
    OnCreateThread();
    OnExitThread();
    return nullptr;
}
```

---

In case you might want `OnExitThread` to be called even when the thread has been terminated prematurely, you might want to use `pthread_cleanup_push` to register it as a callback.

---

PS. The `start_routine` callback must return `void*`.

Comment: That's not exactly true about `std::thread` API. You don't have a direct callback, true, but you can achieve this effect easily by declaring a global object with `thread_local` storage spec. Your solution is pointless; the problem isn't to have functions called, but to attach them to every thread in the application, also by a library the app is using.

Answer (score 1):

There exists at least a `pthread_cleanup_push` function that lets you add a function that will be called just after thread termination. Never heard about the same for creation, but some API may have such.